# Get variable from one method and use as a private string

Tags: asp.net, methods

I was really hoping someone could help me,
I need to get the variable product from the method GridView1_RowDataBound to the quote value class string product.

Its for a pdf creator and any help would be greatly appreciated as i've been stuck on this for quite a while, please excuse as I'm fairly inexperienced in .net.

Thanks very much!!

```
enter code here
public partial class quotedetail : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private string quoteId;
    private string product;
    private string connectId = "";
    string description = "Save Your Quote as a PDF with your Company Logo and Print out for Customers";

    public string ConnectId { get { return connectId; } }

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connectId = Global.GetConnectionString();
        quoteId = Request.QueryString["quote"];
        product = 


    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            (Master as WebOnlineMasterPage).PageTitle = "Quote - " + quoteId;


            DisplayPage();
        }    
    }

    protected void DisplayPage()
    {    
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new WebOnlineQuote.Quote().GetQuote(ConnectId, quoteId);

            FormView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];




            Page.DataBind();
        }
        catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException ex)
        {
            Global.CheckException(ex);
            description = "Sorry, information about this quote is unavailable.";
            Panel1.Visible = false;
        }

        (Master as WebOnlineMasterPage).PageDescription = description;

    }

    public void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow))
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "className='dataOver'");

            if (e.Row.DataItemIndex % 2 == 1)
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "className='dataAltRow'");
            else
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "className='data'");

            string product = ((DataRow)((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row)["ProductCode"].ToString();

            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onClick", String.Format("document.location='productdetail.aspx?id={0}'", product));


        }
    }

    protected void FormView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // get the expiry date
        bool isopen = (bool)((DataRow)((DataRowView)FormView1.DataItem).Row)["IsOpen"];
        bool expired = (bool)((DataRow)((DataRowView)FormView1.DataItem).Row)["Expired"];

        int viewIndex = 0;

        if (isopen && !expired)
            viewIndex = 1;

        // set appropriate view
        MultiView view = (MultiView)FormView1.FindControl("QuoteProcessView");

        view.ActiveViewIndex = viewIndex;
    }

    protected void AcceptQuote_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("checkout.aspx?quote=" + quoteId);
    }


    protected void Requote_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("requestquote.aspx?quote=" + quoteId);
    }


    // ********************PDF Start********************


    protected void SaveAsPdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet quote = new WebOnlineQuote.Quote().GetQuote(ConnectId, quoteId);
        Document document = CreateDocument();
        PdfDocumentRenderer renderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer();
        renderer.Document = document;
        renderer.RenderDocument();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        renderer.PdfDocument.Save(ms);
        byte[] pdfBytes = ms.ToArray();


        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=quote.pdf");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", pdfBytes.Length.ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBytes);
        Response.StatusCode = 200;
        Response.End();
    }

    public Document CreateDocument()
    {

        Document document = new Document();
        document.Info.Title = "A sample invoice";
        document.Info.Subject = "Demonstrates how to create an invoice.";
        DefineStyles(document);
        TextFrame addressFrame;
        MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Table table;
        CreatePage(document, out addressFrame, out table );
        FillContent(document, addressFrame, table);
        return document;
    }

    void DefineStyles(Document document)
    {
        // Get the predefined style Normal.
        MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Style style = document.Styles["Normal"];
        // Because all styles are derived from Normal, the next line changes the 
        // font of the whole document. Or, more exactly, it changes the font of
        // all styles and paragraphs that do not redefine the font.
        style.Font.Name = "Verdana";

        style = document.Styles[StyleNames.Header];
        style.ParagraphFormat.AddTabStop("16cm", TabAlignment.Right);

        style = document.Styles[StyleNames.Footer];
        style.ParagraphFormat.AddTabStop("8cm", TabAlignment.Center);

        // Create a new style called Table based on style Normal
        style = document.Styles.AddStyle("Table", "Normal");
        style.Font.Name = "Verdana";
        style.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
        style.Font.Size = 9;

        // Create a new style called Reference based on style Normal
        style = document.Styles.AddStyle("Reference", "Normal");
        style.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = "5mm";
        style.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = "5mm";
        style.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.AddTabStop("16cm", TabAlignment.Right);
    }

    void CreatePage(Document document, out TextFrame addressFrame, out MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Table table)
    {

        // Each MigraDoc document needs at least one section.
        Section section = document.AddSection();

        // Put a logo in the header
        MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.Image image = section.Headers.Primary.AddImage(Server.MapPath("~/images/cnwlogo.jpg"));
        image.Height = "2.5cm";
        image.LockAspectRatio = true;
        image.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Line;
        image.RelativeHorizontal = RelativeHorizontal.Margin;
        image.Top = ShapePosition.Top;
        image.Left = ShapePosition.Right;
        image.WrapFormat.Style = WrapStyle.Through;

        // Create footer
        Paragraph paragraph = section.Footers.Primary.AddParagraph();
        paragraph.AddText("PowerBooks Inc · Sample Street 42 · 56789 Cologne · Germany");
        paragraph.Format.Font.Size = 9;
        paragraph.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;

        // Create the text frame for the address
        addressFrame = section.AddTextFrame();
        addressFrame.Height = "3.0cm";
        addressFrame.Width = "7.0cm";
        addressFrame.Left = ShapePosition.Left;
        addressFrame.RelativeHorizontal = RelativeHorizontal.Margin;
        addressFrame.Top = "5.0cm";
        addressFrame.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Page;

        // Put sender in address frame
        paragraph = addressFrame.AddParagraph("PowerBooks Inc · Sample Street 42 · 56789 Cologne");
        paragraph.Format.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
        paragraph.Format.Font.Size = 7;
        paragraph.Format.SpaceAfter = 3;

        // Add the print date field
        paragraph = section.AddParagraph();
        paragraph.Format.SpaceBefore = "8cm";
        paragraph.Style = "Reference";
        paragraph.AddFormattedText("INVOICE", TextFormat.Bold);
        paragraph.AddTab();
        paragraph.AddText("Cologne, ");
        paragraph.AddDateField("dd.MM.yyyy");

        // Create the item table
        table = section.AddTable();
        table.Style = "Table";
        table.Borders.Color = Colors.DarkBlue;
        table.Borders.Width = 0.25;
        table.Borders.Left.Width = 0.5;
        table.Borders.Right.Width = 0.5;
        table.Rows.LeftIndent = 0;

        // Before you can add a row, you must define the columns
        Column column = table.AddColumn("3cm");
        column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;

        column = table.AddColumn("5cm");
        column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;

        column = table.AddColumn("1cm");
        column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;

        column = table.AddColumn("1cm");
        column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;

        column = table.AddColumn("2cm");
        column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;

        column = table.AddColumn("2cm");
        column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;

        column = table.AddColumn("2cm");
        column.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;

        // Create the header of the table
        CreateHeaderRow(table);

        table.SetEdge(0, 0, 7, 1, Edge.Box, MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.BorderStyle.Single, 0.75, Color.Empty);

        //create data table




    }

    private static void CreateHeaderRow(MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Table table)
    {
        Row headerRow1 = table.AddRow();
        headerRow1.HeadingFormat = true;
        headerRow1.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
        headerRow1.Format.Font.Bold = true;
        headerRow1.Shading.Color = Colors.AliceBlue;
        headerRow1.Cells[0].AddParagraph("PRODUCT");
        headerRow1.Cells[0].Format.Font.Bold = false;
        headerRow1.Cells[0].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
        headerRow1.Cells[0].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        headerRow1.Cells[0].MergeDown = 1;
        headerRow1.Cells[1].AddParagraph("DESCRIPTION");
        headerRow1.Cells[1].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
        headerRow1.Cells[1].MergeDown = 1;
        headerRow1.Cells[2].AddParagraph("QTY");
        headerRow1.Cells[2].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
        headerRow1.Cells[2].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        headerRow1.Cells[2].MergeDown = 1;

        headerRow1.Cells[3].AddParagraph("UNIT");
        headerRow1.Cells[3].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
        headerRow1.Cells[3].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        headerRow1.Cells[3].MergeDown = 1;

        headerRow1.Cells[4].AddParagraph("PRICE");
        headerRow1.Cells[4].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
        headerRow1.Cells[4].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        headerRow1.Cells[4].MergeDown = 1;

        headerRow1.Cells[5].AddParagraph("TAX");
        headerRow1.Cells[5].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
        headerRow1.Cells[5].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        headerRow1.Cells[5].MergeDown = 1;

        headerRow1.Cells[6].AddParagraph("TOTAL");
        headerRow1.Cells[6].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
        headerRow1.Cells[6].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
        headerRow1.Cells[6].MergeDown = 1;


    }

    class QuoteItemRow
    {
        protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow))
            {
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "className='dataOver'");

                if (e.Row.DataItemIndex % 2 == 1)
                    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "className='dataAltRow'");
                else
                    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "className='data'");

                string product = ((DataRow)((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row)["ProductID"].ToString();

                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onClick", String.Format("document.location='productdetail.aspx?id={0}'", product));

            }
        }

        public QuoteItemRow(decimal quantity, decimal price, decimal discount, string itemNumber, string title)
        {
            Quantity = quantity;
            Price = price;
            Discount = discount;
            ItemNumber = itemNumber;
            Title = title;

        }

        public decimal Quantity;
        public decimal Discount;
        public decimal Price;
        public string ItemNumber;
        public string Title;

    }

    void FillContent(Document document, TextFrame addressFrame, MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Table table)
    {








            Paragraph paragraph = addressFrame.AddParagraph();
            paragraph.AddText("Joe Bloggs");
            paragraph.AddLineBreak();
            paragraph.AddText("12 Some St");
            paragraph.AddLineBreak();
            paragraph.AddText(product);



            // Iterate the invoice items
            decimal totalExtendedPrice = 0;




            QuoteItemRow[] items = new QuoteItemRow[] {
                new QuoteItemRow (2.0m, 3.4m, 0.2m, "3213421", product ),
                new QuoteItemRow (2.4m, 3.4m, 0.0m, "3534DD21", quoteId ),
                new QuoteItemRow (8, 0.4m, 0.1m, "908587", quoteId ),

            };

            foreach (QuoteItemRow item in items)
            {
                decimal quantity = item.Quantity;
                decimal price = item.Price;
                decimal discount = item.Discount;

                // Each item fills two rows
                Row row1 = table.AddRow();
                Row row2 = table.AddRow();
                row1.TopPadding = 1.5;
                row1.Cells[0].Shading.Color = Colors.LightGray;
                row1.Cells[0].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

                row1.Cells[1].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
                row1.Cells[2].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
                row1.Cells[3].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
                row1.Cells[4].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
                row1.Cells[5].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
                row1.Cells[6].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;



                paragraph = row1.Cells[1].AddParagraph();
                paragraph.AddFormattedText(item.Title, TextFormat.Bold);
                row2.Cells[1].AddParagraph(item.Quantity.ToString());
                row2.Cells[2].AddParagraph("$" + price.ToString("0.00"));
                row2.Cells[3].AddParagraph("$" + discount.ToString("0.0"));
                row2.Cells[4].AddParagraph();
                row2.Cells[5].AddParagraph("$" + price.ToString("0.00"));
                decimal extendedPrice = quantity * price;
                extendedPrice = extendedPrice * (100 - discount) / 100;
                row1.Cells[5].AddParagraph("$" + extendedPrice.ToString("0.00"));
                row1.Cells[5].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
                totalExtendedPrice += extendedPrice;

                table.SetEdge(0, table.Rows.Count - 2, 6, 2, Edge.Box, MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.BorderStyle.Single, 0.75);
            }

            // Add an invisible row as a space line to the table
            Row row = table.AddRow();
            row.Borders.Visible = false;

            // Add the total price row
            row = table.AddRow();
            row.Cells[0].Borders.Visible = false;
            row.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Total Price");
            row.Cells[0].Format.Font.Bold = true;
            row.Cells[0].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;
            row.Cells[0].MergeRight = 4;
            row.Cells[5].AddParagraph(totalExtendedPrice.ToString("0.00") + " €");

            // Add the VAT row
            row = table.AddRow();
            row.Cells[0].Borders.Visible = false;
            row.Cells[0].AddParagraph("VAT (19%)");
            row.Cells[0].Format.Font.Bold = true;
            row.Cells[0].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;
            row.Cells[0].MergeRight = 4;
            row.Cells[5].AddParagraph((0.19m * totalExtendedPrice).ToString("0.00") + " €");

            // Add the additional fee row
            row = table.AddRow();
            row.Cells[0].Borders.Visible = false;
            row.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Shipping and Handling");
            row.Cells[5].AddParagraph(0.ToString("0.00") + " €");
            row.Cells[0].Format.Font.Bold = true;
            row.Cells[0].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;
            row.Cells[0].MergeRight = 4;

            // Add the total due row
            row = table.AddRow();
            row.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Total Due");
            row.Cells[0].Borders.Visible = false;
            row.Cells[0].Format.Font.Bold = true;
            row.Cells[0].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;
            row.Cells[0].MergeRight = 4;
            totalExtendedPrice += 0.19m * totalExtendedPrice;
            row.Cells[5].AddParagraph(totalExtendedPrice.ToString("0.00") + " €");

            // Set the borders of the specified cell range
            table.SetEdge(5, table.Rows.Count - 4, 1, 4, Edge.Box, MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.BorderStyle.Single, 0.75);

            // Add the notes paragraph
            paragraph = document.LastSection.AddParagraph();
            paragraph.Format.SpaceBefore = "1cm";
            paragraph.Format.Borders.Width = 0.75;
            paragraph.Format.Borders.Distance = 3;
            paragraph.Format.Borders.Color = Colors.DarkBlue;
            paragraph.Format.Shading.Color = Colors.LightGray;
        }

}
```

Comment: please specify limited code so any one can help and give more discription about your problem

Comment: Can you format code in different blocks and specify where you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution would be to put the value in a Session

```
Session.Add("ProductCode", ((DataRow)((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row)["ProductCode"].ToString());
```

To get the value:

```
Session["ProductCode"].ToString()
```

Keep in mind though that you are doing this in the item databound, in the event that you are expecting multiple values for product code, I would suggest storing the values in a collection prior to putting it in the Session.

i.e.

```
if(Session["ProductCode"] != null)
{
List<string> pcodes = Session["ProductCode"] as List<string>();
pcodes.Add(((DataRow)((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row)["ProductCode"].ToString());
Session.Add("ProductCode", pcodes);
}
else
{
List<string> pcodes = new List<string>();
pcodes.Add(((DataRow)((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row)["ProductCode"].ToString());
Session.Add("ProductCode", pcodes);
}
```

To get the values:

```
Session["ProductCode"] as List<string>()
```

Comment: Thanks very much jr pineda, i got the first part working but the when i try to store as List using the second piece of code I get the error The type or namespace name 'List' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Thanks again for all your help

Comment: I added using System.Collections.Generic; but now i get Cannot implicity convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to string. stuck on this as you were right i need one than one product codes to appear, Thanks again

Comment: To access the values of the list simply use:
pcodes[0]
Note :  the list is an a zero based index collection.